# Trouble using the r package (random)

Tags: r, ssl, random

I want to generate random string and have installed the `random` package.
However, I couldn't run my code and received this error:

> ```
> Error in url(urltxt, ..., method = "libcurl") : cannot open connection
> In addition: Warning message: In url(urltxt, ..., method = "libcurl")
> :   URL 'https://www.random.org/strings/?num=7&len=6&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=off&unique=on&format=plain&rnd=new'
> :   status was 'SSL connect error'
> ```

Here's my code:

```
library("random")
String<-randomStrings(n=7, len = 6, digits = TRUE, upperalpha = TRUE, loweralpha = FALSE, unique = TRUE, check = FALSE)
```

Anybody knows what's the source of this error?

Comment: This may arise from being behind the proxy. Can you access those URL from the browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to access the URL from the browser. Is this due to some firewall issue then? @m0nhawk